# What's the meaning of the icons on the backside of Wii U games?

Tags: wii-u

While building a database of Wii U games, I am struggling with the meaning of the hardware requirement symbols on the backside of the game. I can keep apart the symbols e.g. for Wiimote, Wii U Gamepad, USB stick and headset, but there are a lot of other symbols I don't understand.

Is there a comprehensive list with possible Wii U input methods and accessoires, including the icons which can be found on a game's backside?

Comment: Can you show a picture of the ones that you don't understand?

Comment: Seems like http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/buyers_guide.jsp has not been updated yet with Wii U Icons. A lot of them should be similliar to the Wii ones, so this may help you a bit.

Comment: Here: http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2191/vw54.jpg (2nd and 5th symbol) and http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/5198/zwf3.jpg (last symbol). However, there might be other symbols I haven't seen yet - therefore I wanted a list.

Comment: @YallaT.: Many thanks, this is what I wanted (but didn't find). (If this page included the Wii U icons, you could have posted it as an answer I'd accept.)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find a list of those icons, so for now, I'm going to describe the ones from the screenshots provided in the comments.

[image: First image, as provided in the comments]
From left to right:

- Obviously the [**Wii U GamePad**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U_GamePad): the main controller for the Wii U.
- The [**Wii U Pro Controller**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_U_Pro_Controller#Wii_U_Pro_Controller): a more traditional controller, similar to the Xbox 360 controller.
- The [**Wii Remote**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Remote) aka Wiimote: the main controller for the Wii.
- The [**Nunchuck**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Nunchuk#Nunchuk): an add-on for the Wiimote, adding an analog stick, two shoulder buttons and another accelerometer.
- The [**Classic Controller**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Controller): an add-on for the Wiimote that acts as a traditional controller.
- Possibly the [**PDP headset**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nintendo_Wi-Fi_Connection#PDP_Headset), but it could also refer to headsets in general.

[image: Second image, as provided in the comments]
Last icon:

- The [**Wii Wheel**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wii_Wheel#Wii_Wheel): Actually, it's just a piece of plastic to make the Wiimote feel like a wheel.